# Displaying the property of the selected objects in an array in Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown

I am trying to display the id of the selected objects of the employee array which is a dropdown.

```
export const employees = [
 {index:1,'name':"Josh",'id':"102A"},
 {index:2,'name':"Sam",'id':"598A"},
 {index:3,'name':"Cal",'id':"345A"},
 {index:4,'name':"Elise",'id':"66A"}
];

<app-dropdown
  [(ngModel)]="project.employees"
  [items]="employeesDropdownItems"
  [multiselect]="true"
  (ngModelChange)="onEmployeeChanged()"
  placeholder="Select employee"
>
</app-dropdown>
```

`{{project.employees.id}}` doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: **employees** is an array and you are trying to get the id of a specific employees an array withouth using index ! 
project.employees.id

Comment: What does App-dropdown components does?

Comment: App-dropdown creates a multi-select dropdown element. @VimalPatel

Comment: @Hamza, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: How do you know what items are selected? Do you have any array to store it?

Comment: @Deepak, Im trying to use the data binding concept of Angular to print the selected objects. I am able to view the selected items as a string. I need only employee id to be displayed.

Comment: @Deepak Am i going about this functionality wrong? How else can I achieve it?

Comment: Alright we are almost there. Please show how you print them successfully.

Comment: @Deepak, Sorry for the misunderstanding. I was able to print them when employees was an array with only names. Not an array of objects with names and ids.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print the id of the employees using {{project.employees.id}}. But the problem is that `employees` array has elements of type `{ index: number, name: string, id: string }`. To retrieve any element in this array, you need to know its index. If you are looking to print the first object, you need to provide the starting index, like `project.employees[0]`. If you just wish to print the `id` of the first object, you use `project.employees[0].id`. Similarly, if you wish to print the `id` of all the elements in the array, you need to loop over the entire array and print its `id`.

```js
const employees = [
 {index:1,'name':"Josh",'id':"102A"},
 {index:2,'name':"Sam",'id':"598A"},
 {index:3,'name':"Cal",'id':"345A"},
 {index:4,'name':"Elise",'id':"66A"}
];


let toPrint = [];
employees.forEach(employee => toPrint.push(employee.id))
console.log(toPrint)
```

Or, a more simplified one in JavaScript is map:

```js
const employees = [
 {index:1,'name':"Josh",'id':"102A"},
 {index:2,'name':"Sam",'id':"598A"},
 {index:3,'name':"Cal",'id':"345A"},
 {index:4,'name':"Elise",'id':"66A"}
];

let toPrint = employees.map(employee => employee.id)
console.log(toPrint)
```

In your case, you can write the above logic in your `onEmployeeChanged()` function like:

```js
public toPrint: any;
onEmployeeChanged(){
  // Your existing code here

  // Write your code to handle employee id to print
  this.toPrint = this.project.employees.map(employee => employee.id)).join(", ")
}
```

And in your HTML:

```html
{{toPrint}}
```